# How to use a custom Code Analysis ruleset file on VSTS?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild, code-analysis, azure-pipelines

I have a VS2015 project and I use VSTS for the Continuous integration.
I want to force the execution of Code Analysis during a VSTS build.

I added this MSBuild argument to build the solution and use a ruleset file on the local agent :

```
/p:RunCodeAnalysis=true;CodeAnalysisRuleSet="E:\Tools\VSTS\Code Analysis Rulesets\MyRules.ruleset"
```

But I get these errors :

- CA0064 : No analysis was performed because the specified rule set
  could not be loaded or did not contain any managed code analysis
  rules.
- CA0063 : * Failed to load rule set file 'E:\Tools\VSTS\Code Analysis
  Rulesets\MyRules.ruleset' or one of its dependent rule set files.

Comment: How do you custom ruleset file? What's the result if you build the solution via MSBuild command manually on your machine and build agent machine? Set system.debug variable to true, then queue build and post the detail log here.

Comment: I find I chose the bad agent, which is probably on other server. Thank you.